# android - Activity still leaks even instance is set to null in onDestroy() method

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am stuck with memory leak in my main Activity (NavigationActivity)

```
public static NavigationActivity navigationActivity;

public static NavigationActivity getNavigationActivity() {
    return navigationActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    navigationActivity = NavigationActivity.this;

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (navigationActivity != null) {
        navigationActivity = null;       
    }      
}
```

Where does it leak? and how do I fix it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

I'm using leak canary and this is the leak
[image]

Comment: I looked up your profile and saw you're not accepting answers at all. You should do it for future readers, so they know which answer is correct. Downvoting for that reason

Comment: Can you open NavigationActivity (+) stacktree in leakCanary screenshot. What is this navigationActivity class?

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    navigationActivity = null;
}
```

but using static reference of Activity is very bad practise, don't do it.

In the most cases you can use *activity.this* reference or something like getActivity() method.

Answer (score 1):

Make the instance a [`WeakReference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

```
private final WeakReference<Activity> navigationActivity;
```

Also `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called. Read more on onDestroy() [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

You should set activity instance to null in `onStop method`, because `onDestroy` might not be called.

From Android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29):

> protected void onDestroy ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Perform any final cleanup before an activity is
>   destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing
>   (someone called **finish()** on it, or because the system is temporarily
>   destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can
>   distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.
>
> Note: **do not count on this method being called** as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

Comment: Instead I would say clearing the object is similar to free up resources and its a good place to clean up the objects which we don't need any more.

Answer (score 1):

You cleared up the reference inside your activity. But class `ContactsCompletionView` still has strong reference to your activity. The best way to avoid this leak is not to expose link to your activity. 
But if you really need this you can use `WeakReference` to your `Activity`. So your method `getNavigationActivity()` might looks like this:

```
public static WeakReference<NavigationActivity> navigationActivityRef;
{
    public static WeakReference<NavigationActivity> getNavigationActivity() {
      if(navigationActivityRef == null) {
          navigationActivityRef = new WeakReference<>(this);
      }
      return navigationActivityRef;
}
```